# Unable to flag comments anymore: the pop-up windows does not display correctly

Tags: support, bug, comment, flagging, user-interface

It seems that [the recent redesign of the window that pops up when attempting to flag comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313754/updated-comment-flagging-supporting-the-new-code-of-conduct) has some subtle bug: when it pops up, it does so [in the upper left corner of the browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2XOV.jpg) in such a way that most of its content is outside the visible area of the window (and thus is unusable). I have to manually resize the browser window a bit, in order for the pop-up window to suddenly become centered (and fully visible) in the browser window as it was supposed to be. This happens on Firefox 52.9.0 ESR 32bit (no extensions), on Windows XP SP3 (yeah, yeah, I know, don't ask...). I'm having this problem on MSE, MO and SO, so it seems to be a SE-wide bug. Could a moderator please forward this to the SE team, or to whoever is in charge of these issues?

The above behaviour does not happen when flagging answers or questions.

Comment: Seems like an issue to take to big meta?

Comment: It's bottom-right rather than top-left for me. And resizing doesn't help here. It would already help if the dialogue would be [made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313770/177145) draggable [again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313631/make-the-comment-flag-dialog-draggable-again).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Quite right, but I don't have an account there, and I wouldn't want to make one only for such occasional issues.

Comment: @DanielFischer: it's the upper-left corner of the browser window, and the lower-right one of the pop-up window. And resizing does help, but it is annoying to have to do so every time.

Comment: The dialogue is positioned differently for me. It's at - and beyond - the bottom of the browser window, on the right hand side (but a little bit away from the right edge of the browser window). I can flag with a canned reason by selecting the reason and typing the enter key, but the text-field for the custom flag reason, and the "submit" bottom are outside my window (and I haven't found a way to move them inside). Different browsers, different (but related) problems.

Comment: SE monitors all per site metas for bug reports; it's true that posting on the main meta can have advantages (as it gets more visibility more quickly) but there is no necessity to do so either.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Possibly relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313777. I still see no mention on Meta.SE of the problem described in my post; since you have an account there, could you please act there on my behalf? Thank you.

Comment: See [comment flags broken](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/313444)

Comment: @JosephQuinsey: Excellent, thank you. Now waiting for the SE staff to fix it. (It seems that it only happens with Firefox.)